# Passing php var with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, getelementbyid

I'm trying to pass a php var that is a string using Javascript, but in the final result the string gets cmmented in html. Here's my code:

**PHP:**

```
$txtVar = "My text";
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var txt = '<?php echo $txtVar; ?>';
document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = txt;
```

**HTML(result):**

```
<div id="MyDiv"><!--?php echo $txtVar ; ?--></div>
```

I just want the string value to be printed in my html, withou the comments ()

Comment: You cannot use php inside javascript. That just won't work. php is on the server, javascript on the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Comment: Is the $txtvar variable being set within the same document within which the JavaScript runs? I ask because I found this method: http://p2p.wrox.com/php-faqs/11606-q-how-do-i-pass-php-variables-javascript.html

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, perhaps you could provide what you consider the best answer?

Comment: @erickb not the same issue

Comment: I guess this javascript containing php tag is not in a .php file?

Comment: It's a js file, @arkascha is right, I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First print the PHP variable value in another HTML entity like hidden input HTml tag and after that pick the hidden value using JavaScript and assign into your desire tag.

1. **In Your page.**

   ```
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $txtVar; ?>" id="phptext" name="phptext" />
   ```
2. **JavaScript code:**

document.getElementById('MyDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('phptext').value;

This is works.

Comment: That's the correct solution,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

```
<?php
$txtVar = "My text";
?>

<div id="MyDiv"></div>

<script>
var txt = "<?php echo $txtVar; ?>";
var element = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
element.innerHTML = txt;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your javascript is an external file, you can just rename it with .php extension, and then retrieve it with

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='yourscript.php'></script>
```

Comment: That's completely wrong. You can't read PHP like this. Also, `language` attribute is deprecated, `type` is optional.

Comment: True about both attributes, even though that's not the point. Yes, you can read it, as long as you set the correct header http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Certainly this is doable. As long as `yourscript.php` outputs javascript. That is a quite common solution to create specific js snippets, actually. Though I agree that is has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Agree with both of you, as long as PHP has `text/javascript` as Content Type, it can be used as JavaScript.